# Using Migration Asst, have gone from Mac 1 to Mac 2, but now Mac 2 back to Mac 1?

Tags: macbook-pro, sharing, migration

I had to send MacBook Pro #1 out for repair and used Migration Assistant to temporarily work on a loaner (MacBook Pro #2).

Now #1 is back. Do I:

1. Use M.A. to go from #2 to #1, hoping it magically merges and resolves the differences in my user account existing on #1?
2. Reformat and reinstall the OS on #1, and use M.A. to go from #2 to #1?
3. Some other optimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you did a full migration from MBP #1 to MBP #2, then I'd probably go with your second option (although that may depend on how long MBP #1 was away for and how much work you've done since).

The only downside of this approach is that some 3rd party software *may* need you to reactivate them in order to use them. It's not really a problem, just may add a little inconvenience if you happen to be in that situation.

Since you asked, there are indeed other solutions, such as cloning the drive from MBP #2 to MBP #1 using software such as [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) You can also use Disk Utility to do the same thing.

Comment: But they are different model MBPs, wouldn't the direct hard drive cloning present some issues?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It used to be, quite some years ago now, that macOS installations were in part customised to suit specific models of Mac. However, that hasn't been the case for a long time. For example, if you start up MBP #2 in Target Disk Mode and connect it to MBP #1, you could just boot MBP #1 from MBP #2 as if it was just an external hard drive. You'd be able to use your system pretty much as normal. In fact, I've used a cloned system for troubleshooting purposes by having a whole heap of diagnostic software installed, and just connect the *clone* drive to a Mac and off I go.

Comment: The only real exception to this approach is if the version of macOS being cloned is not actually compatible with the hardware. For example, if you buy a brand new MBP today and then tried to restore from a clone of an El Capitan installation, well that's just not going to work because the firmware of current model MBPs won't run with El Capitan.